# Does Buck have a platform name macro?

Tags: buck

Buck has some [useful macros](https://buckbuild.com/function/string_parameter_macros.html), such as `$(location :rule)`. Does it also have a macro for getting the platform name?

I need to execute some custom logic based on the build-target's platform.

Answer (score 0):

It does, but it only supports it for some properties of native libraries.  You can search for `$(platform` on the Buck's website for the various places.